# UWP App Display Issues When Using External Monitor

Tags: uwp, monitor, display

How does a UWP app remembers its window size and position?  I am trying to figure out how do I make it show in the center of the screen and in a set size but the app always shows as either maximized or minimized (in the task-bar).

Even more, if my laptop was connected to an external monitor, disconnecting from that monitor, then running app ends up with the app Window (MainPage) showing only as minimized (in the taskbar).

Clicking on it will not restore it.  I figured out, it somehow thinks that my laptop is still connected to the monitor and probably thinks it is showing it there.

I even tried adding lines to set the size like

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Windows.Foundation.Size(300, 400); 

    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = 
       ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize; 
    ...
}
```

If I hover over the UWP app icon in the taskbar, it shows it in the small popup window and I can right click in its toolbar and choose btw Restore, Maximize, Move, Size, Minimize.  Only Maximize will show it on my screen though.  This results in having app either maximized on my screen or being minimized in the taskbar but I cannot move, resize or restore it.

The only way I found to fix it is to disconnect external monitor, run the app.  This way, it shows on my laptop and I can resize it to the size I like.  Then if I minimize it and restore it, that works.  Now if I connect external monitor again and run it, the app will show on my laptop screen fine.

Comment: “but the app always shows as either maximized or minimized” , could  you please tell which device you are using for testing?  What's the mode you are setting for the external monitor? Duplicate、Extend、or Second screen only? I think this is not a development issue, change the mode to duplicate or extend may resolve your issue.

Comment: The mode is extend seeing to duplicate is not resolving issue.

Comment: partial solution found here and it is working good for me [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6445232-9219-4fd0-aba4-c285364d9620/uwp-app-cannot-be-resized-shows-only-as-maximized-or-as-minimized-in-taskbar?forum=wpdevelop](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6445232-9219-4fd0-aba4-c285364d9620/uwp-app-cannot-be-resized-shows-only-as-maximized-or-as-minimized-in-taskbar?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per partial solution at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6445232-9219-4fd0-aba4-c285364d9620/uwp-app-cannot-be-resized-shows-only-as-maximized-or-as-minimized-in-taskbar?forum=wpdevelop
, adding following line after InitializeComponent call in the MainPage c-tor resolved issue for me.

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
```